# Merge two endpoint using a different name and schema with Eve

Tags: python-3.x, eve

This is a simplified version of my settings.py:

```
accounts_schema = {
    'username': {
    },
    'password': {
    }
}

accounts = {
    'schema': accounts_schema,
}
```

After a user is created with a POST request to the `/accounts` endpoint, the user's info can be retrived with a GET to `/accounts/<id_of_user>`.
I would like to know if it possible to "merge" two endpoints that are using a different schema so

```
POST /update_accounts/<id_of_user>
```

will point to

```
/accounts/<id_of_user>
```

but update_accounts must have, for example, this schema:

```
update_accounts_schema = {
    'token': {
    },
    'validity': {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://python-eve.org/config#multiple-api-endpoints-one-datasource):

> **Multiple API endpoints can target the same database collection**. For example you can set both admins and /users to read and write from the same people collection on the database.

So you can have `update_accounts` and `accounts` both targeting the same datasource, and each one with its own user privileges/allowed methods, etc.